# App Getting rejected on Play console for contact list although the policy is updated

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have created an app using flutter and wanted to upload it on play store. But for the past 2 month the app is getting rejected for contact list without disclosing error. To be specific here is what the play console rejects it with:

> APK HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ BUT IT IS NOT ADEQUATE
>
> Privacy Policy in Play Console
> Your app is uploading users' contact list information without disclosing it in the privacy policy in Play Console.
> Please make sure your Privacy Policy in Play Console is available on an active, publicly accessible and non-geofenced URL (no PDFs) and is non-editable.
> Privacy Policy in Play Distributed App
> Your app is uploading users' contact list information without posting a privacy policy in Play Distributed App.

Also the app asks for the permission. What should I do to solve this? For reference you can refer the [privacy policy](https://www.vistaarfinance.com/assets/pdf/Vistaar%20Privacy%20Policy_November%202022.pdf) as well.

I have tried providing all the permission in app content in play console.
I have tried to remove contact list usage in case the app might not be using it.
I have tried giving all combination of collected and shared data under contacts in play console
I have tried updating the privacy policy
I have tried creating new apk removing contact required part

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require contacts of the user necessarily and are flexible to remove them as a requirement, this answer can help you.

1. Check if your app's `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` contains contact-related permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

If yes, then remove them from this file since you won't be using them.

2. It is possible that one or more of the packages that you are using in your flutter app has the above-mentioned permissions in their manifest files. When you build your app, a **merged manifest** is created.

You can find your app's merged manifest after you have built your code at:

`build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests`

The "merged manifest" is the result of merging all of the manifests from your app's modules and their dependencies. When you build your app, the Android build system combines the manifests from all of the app's modules and its dependencies, and generates a single, merged manifest that contains all of the information from all of the individual manifests. This merged manifest is then included in the APK that is generated by the build process.

Since these packages might contain the contact permissions, the play store might reject the build. To overcome this, add

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" tools:node="remove"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" tools:node="remove" />
```

in your app's manifest. This will explicitly remove these permissions on a parent level and will make sure these permissions don't appear in the merged manifest.

### Regarding privacy policy

After going through your app's privacy policy, I couldn't find any sentence mentioning that you fetch the user's contact list and what you do with it.

Maybe you can add a clause in your privacy policy along the lines of the following:

> From time to time, during your use of the App, we may
> require access to certain additional information such as SMS, Image,
> and contact list. Prior to accessing any such additional information,
> explicit consent shall be sought from you. Please note that even after
> consent has been provided by you, we only read transactional or
> promotional SMS and do not open, access, or read any personal SMS.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Actually I want those permission and don't want to remove it. The method I tried was removing the app content in play console just for the sake for trial and error. Also, I thought that contacts would be same as contact list. Let me give it a try. Will mention this inside the app as a dialog work before the user could login?

Comment: Yes, you can show a popup that mentions why you need this permission and how will it affect the user's experience in the app and then move on to asking permissions natively, doesn't really matter before or after login. It should just be before you ask for the permission